# AWS: Target.FailedHealthChecks - Site always in "severe" state

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, healthcheck

My Elastic Beanstalk application is in a constant `severe` state... even though it's working absolutely fine.

Looking at the Health screen it says that 100% of its requests are `3xx`, and looking at the logs, this is apparently confirmed:

`[29/Nov/2017:10:07:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 356 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"`

This makes perfect sense, as `/` will 302 Redirect you to the "login" page.

The thing is, I've told AWS to NOT use `/` when checking for health, but instead to use `/news` which should always return a `200`, whether you're logged in or not:

[image]

I've tried changing the Health check URL to other suitable endpoints, and restarting the EC2 instance, but it always returns to checking `/` (according to the logs). I've given it 12 hours to see if it would change in time, too.

So why does it keep checking `/` and returning a `severe` state? What can I do to fix this? Is it a Security Group issue perhaps (even though the site is open to the public)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the error was caused by a Heath Check for the **Application Load Balancer**, *not the Elastic Beanstalk application*. The ALB needs its target changing in a different place ([see the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html)).

It was an easy fix once I knew that:

> To modify the health check settings of a target group using the
>   console
>
> 1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
> 2. On the navigation pane, under LOAD BALANCING, choose Target Groups.
> 3. Select the target group.
> 4. On the Health checks tab, choose Edit.
> 5. On the Edit target group page, modify the settings as needed, and then choose Save.

Comment: Yeah, the health check will consider any non-2XX error code to be a failure.

Comment: Seems to me they consider any non 200 code to be a failure in fact.

Comment: @Dan No, that's not the case.

Comment: By which I mean to say that it asks for a specific code... and if it doesn't match, then it's a failure. So if your health check code is 200 and your response code is 201 then voila.

Answer (score 0):

I was running a Django server in a multi-container Docker environment with Elastic Beanstalk on Amazon Linux 2 and was absolutely tearing my hair out over this problem.  I thought it was a Nginx issue, but even with a running Nginx container it still wasn't fixed!  So my app was accessible and running, but the status was severe and it only gave me a target mismatch error on the EB health dashboard...no code though!  Using Django Reinhardt's answer, I found out that the error code was displayed in the target group section of the load balancer settings!  Sure enough, I was getting `400` errors on the health checks.

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54739178/elastic-beanstalk-health-severe-failing-with-a-code-400-even-though-i-can-vi), I learned that the health check occurs on a private AWS IP!  If this IP is not in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, then it will give 400 errors!  After testing with `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` (don't do this in production!), the issue went away!

Not sure if a Nginx container is still necessary.  Next steps are to dynamically add relevant AWS IP's to `ALLOWED HOSTS` (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54739178/elastic-beanstalk-health-severe-failing-with-a-code-400-even-though-i-can-vi))

Answer (score 0):

I created a new environment with a "classic" load balancer and copied all the settings from my existing environment and it sorted this out. My "application" load balancer was misconfigured and I didn't bother trying to figure out what the problem was.